# Tomcat service running on EC2 Instance

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2

I have Tomcat hosting a web app on port 8080 within an EC2 micro instance. From my home network I can get to the web page no problem, but from any other network 3G cell, or my co-worker's home network the website "stops responding" and never connects. I've checked the security settings for the instance multiple times and have set port 8080 for access from 0.0.0.0/0. I consistently connect from my home network without issues. Is there an EC2 setting that only allows incoming traffic from one ip?  Any ideas on why I can only connect from my home ip?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you using the public DNS name for your EC2 instance?
2. Try accessing your IP/port from an external tool such as:
   http://www.watchmouse.com/en/checkit.php
3. Run `netstat -a` or `tcpdump` to see if your request actually arrives on the server or if there is some application issue preventing a response

Answer (score 0):

You might want to think about using Amazon Elastic Beanstalk Tomcat instead.  Each instance of Beanstalk is the same price as a node of Linux or Windows.  Also, you can compile and publish directly to the Beanstalk instance from Eclipse.  All of this takes a little bit of money of course, probably as much as 12 cents per hour, depending on how you deploy.